# Getting xdebug to work on my dev server

Tags: ubuntu, windows-7, port, xdebug

I am trying to get xdebug to work on my ubuntu 11 04 server. Everything seems setup right and I do see xdebug from phpinfo(). I installed with `apt-get install php5-xdebug`. The problem is that anytime I put my workstation(windows 7) ip in xdebug.ini as

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so

[debug]
; Remote settings
xdebug.remote_autostart=off
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.0.49
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_log=/home/someone/xdebug.log
```

No webpage works. They just timeout for everyone connected to this server. If I put a coworkers ip in (he is on linux) web pages load without problem. I tought maybe my port 9000 was blocked by windows firewall but I opened the port and everything and still it hangs.

I hope I am clear. I do not see anything in xdebug.log or apaches error logs. I do restart apache after every changes to xdebug.ini. ALso as I said xdebug does load since it shows up in phpinfo().

I'll add any info you guys deeme necessary I am not sure what you need to help me. 
I found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/260354/remote-debugging-php-windows) question but no one helped him:(

edit: other things I have tried, disabling antivirus, starting a debug session from netbeans. Nothing works.

Answer (score 2):

On the Ubuntu machine, try `telnet 192.168.0.49 9000` (or `nc 192.168.0.49 9000`) to see if you come through.

You can also turn on the `remote_log` it should record all attempts of sending debugging information to your host:

```
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for taking the time to help! Telnet fails to connect and I did enable remote_log but its empty.

Comment: Telnet failing to connect shows that your Windows system is not ready to receive the debugging information. Do you use an IDE? You need to enable the debugging port there.

Comment: I use netbeans and zend studio 8. I did enable the debuging port (9000) there.

Comment: yes but obviously you don't come through to that port. so it might be a firewall or malware protection after all.